# Drawing image stamps along a path with Cairo

Tags: cairo

As part of my initial research, to see if using Cairo is a good fit for us, I'm looking to see if I can obtain an (x,y) point at a given distance from the start of a path. I have looked over the Cairo examples and APIs but I haven't found anything to suggest this is possible. It would be a pain if we had to build our own Bezier path implementation from scratch.

On android there is a class called [PathMeasure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html). This allows getting an (x,y) point at a given distance from the start of the path. This allows me to draw a stamp easily at the wanted distance being able to produce something like the image below.
[image]

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: In the second example you seem to specify also a rotation and a scale for your stamp. Is this also part of the requirements?

Comment: From what you could understand, are the Cairo and Java Android paths concept matching? http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-Paths.description and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html The documentation for Cairo is not that clear to me...

Comment: The Android and Cairo paths seem to be similar in that they hold points A to B to C. As in Android and it seems with Cairo, when you commit to draw the path the computation happens internally to draw the pixels between those points. I think I need to just download the source and dive in with actual code testing :/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have an uncomplete understanding of what you mean with "path", it seems that you can accomplish the task by starting from [this guide](http://cairographics.org/samples/image/). You would use multiple `cr` (image location, rotation, scale) and just one `image` instance.

From what I can understand from your image, you'll need to use blending (e.g. the alpha channel), I would say setting pixel by pixel the alpha channel (transparency) proportional to/same as your original grayscale values, and all the R G B pixels values to black (0).

For acting directly on your input image (on the file you will be loading), by googling "convert grayscale image to alpha" I found several results for Photoshop, some for gimp, I don't know what would you have available.

Otherwise you will have to do directly within your code accessing the image pixels. To read/edit pixel values you can use [cairo_image_surface_get_data](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-image-surface-get-data). First you have to create a destination image with [cairo_image_surface_create](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-image-surface-create)
using format [CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t)

Similarly, you can use [cairo_mask](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-mask) drawing a black rectangle of the size of your image, after having created an alpha channel image of format [CAIRO_FORMAT_A8](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t) from your original image (again, accessing pixel by pixel seems the only possible way given the limitations of [cairo_image_surface_create_from_png](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-image-surface-create-from-png)).

Using [cairo_paint_with_alpha](http://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-paint-with-alpha) in place of cairo_paint is not suitable because the alpha channel would be constant for the whole image.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. So your provided answer does help with a particular area I was going to eventually dive into. That is the second part. However, the main concern for deciding to use Cairo or not is if I can read the actual pixel position of the path at any given distance.  Please see the updated question.